# REST API with Ruby on Rails and ReactJS

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rest

I'm currently working on building a simple REST API using Ruby on Rails. I noticed that a lot of the things I did were a bit redundant, especially the models. Just to clarify: I want this to be a REST API which returns JSON, without any views (I want to be able to access it from different applications, mainly Apache Cordova). Within Cordova I wanted to use ReactJS.

Sadly, my Rails controllers all look like this:

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @students = Student.all
    render json: @students
  end

  def create
    if @student.present?
      render nothing: true, status: :conflict
    else
      @student = Student.new(student_params)
      if @student.save
        render json: @student
      else
        render nothing: true, status: :bad_request
      end
    end
  end

  def show
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    render json: @student.classes
  end

  def update
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    @student.update(student_params)
    if @student.save
      render json: @student
    else
      render nothing: true, status: :bad_request
    end
  end

  def delete
    if Student.destroy(params[:id])
      render nothing: true, status: :ok
    else
      render nothing: true, status: :bad_request
    end
  end

  private
    def student_params
      params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :grade_id)
    end
end
```

I literally got three of them with only the classname changed. Is there a smarter way to organize this? I may have to change override some functions, but some functions will be identical.

I also have a few database relationships, for example grades and classes to teachers and students. Does anyone have some information about best practices for this? I seem to be creating a lot of "relationship" tables for these many-to-many relationships.

For the RoR Rest API Part I found [this tutorial](https://blog.codelation.com/rails-restful-api-just-add-water/).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your controller. It's a basic bare bones controller and there's nothing you can do to improve it. If you need some feedback on your models you'll need to post them up.

Comment: There's nothing in my models except the logic for the database yet. I did find out a better way to do controllers. The problem was that I had to write the same code with different classnames for every model, but the tutorial I posted fixed this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is an interesting idea, although I haven't personally used it when building REST APIs.

Here's some code which shows how it could be done.

I tested the following code to ensure that it works. To test it:

1. make a todo model with a :name column
2. add `resources :todos` to the routes
3. visit localhost:3000/todos

...

```
# app/controllers/todos_controller.rb
class TodosController < ApplicationController
  include GenericController
  RecordClass = Todo
  def record_params
    params.require(:todo).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

You can see that there are only two points of customization in each controller.
You'll have to specify the `RecordClass` and your secure parameters method.

The following "generic controller" was built using Rails' default scaffold controller.
You can customize it to follow your own default controller logic.

```
# app/controllers/generic_controller.rb
module GenericController

  before_action :set_instance, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @records = RecordClass.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @record = RecordClass.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @record = RecordClass.new(record_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @record.save
        format.html { redirect_to @record, notice: '#{RecordClass} was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @record }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @record.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @record.update(record_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @record, notice: '#{RecordC;ass} was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @record }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @record.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @record.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to records_url, notice: #{'RecordClass} was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_record
      @record = RecordClass.find(params[:id])
    end
```